# Generating choice list (dropdown) in toolbox to allow user to select field in CSV as input?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, parameters, python-toolbox, choice-list

I need to input a csv as parameter 1. Parameter 2 should be a dropdown displaying the various fields (the headerline) where I can select a column to use for geoprocessing.

- Param1:  c:\my.csv
- Param2: (dropdown) select header